# Blade to Thymeleaf templates and views conversion doubts

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, laravel-blade

When using the Blade template engine with PHP and Laravel, there is the concept of layout extension with the `@extends`, `@yield` and `@section` tags.

Now this is a fenomenal approach in my opinion, 'cause you do not have to include the usual header and footer for every view, and at the same time you can return the appropriate view from the controller.

Migrating to Thymeleaf I'm having an hard time finding an equivalend way. Let's also say the Thymeleaf documentation is not by a point near to the Laravel-Blade one.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Blade, but I believe you're looking for something like the Thymeleaf Layout Dialect: https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect

Comment: Yeah, right! But what a mess. Really. Spring is not clear by itself (millions of configurations and millions of ways to do it), plus Thymeleaf "ecosystem"... Bah

Comment: @LppEdd https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines if you want to switch to another template engine.With spring boot you gotta do 0 configurations on thymeleaf, freemaker or groovy. The reason why thymeleaf looks messy is it's syntax is focused on prototyping. Out of the box you can open any thymeleaf template in your browser without running the project and you can render your layers by using thymeleaf layout dialect JS. This is mostly useful for frontend devs cause they dont have to learn Thymeleaf or to run the project. And it is easy for you to integrate as well